# MIN and MAX strings

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the length of the longest and shortest city names in the city table
This is the code I'm trying to use

```
SELECT Name, char_length(Name) from city WHERE char_length(Name)=(SELECT MAX(char_length(name)), MIN(char_length(name))from city);
```

but I get the error I can only have one operand... It does work when I get rid of either the MAX or the MIN. I need them both to run in one query

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `=` to compare one value to a subquery that returns two columns.

Try this:

```
SELECT c.Name, char_length(c.Name) FROM city AS c
JOIN (SELECT MAX(char_length(name)) AS max, MIN(char_length(name)) AS min FROM city) AS t
  ON char_length(c.Name) IN (t.max, t.min);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm, now to go through and get it understood in my head!

Comment: @Bill Karwin Why not write it like I did in my answer?

Comment: @Alex, because your method can't get the Names themselves, only the lengths.  I know this wasn't part of the original question as stated, but I anticipate it'll be the natural next question.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select min(char_length(Name)), max(char_length(Name)) from city;
```

Comment: The issue is that you're not getting the city name.

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho But the author wants "get the length of the longest and shortest city names in the city table" only

Comment: That is what the question states but not what the query is fetching :)  Requirement analysis... it is always a pain in the neck +1 for the effort, though :)

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
(select name, char_length(name) len from city
order by len asc
limit 1)
union
(select name, char_length(name) len from city
order by len desc
limit 1)
```

Another option:

```
select name, char_length(name) len from city
where char_length(name) in (
  select max(char_length(name)) from city
  union
  select min(char_length(name)) from city
)
```